# return value of fftw_mpi_local_size_3d should depend on c2c, c2r or r2c, right?

Tags: c, mpi, fftw

This may be a stupid question, since it's the first time I use fftw with MPI.

I'm trying to find the amount of memory I have to allocate in each node in an MPI code in order to perform 3-dimensional r2c and c2r transforms. In my case the arrays are distributed as a cube of size n_grid^3, so in principle, if I was using only 1 node, I should allocate n_grid*n_grid*(n_grid/2+1) complex elements and twice as many real ones (I'm using in-place transforms).

Now, according to the FFTW documentation (http://www.fftw.org/doc/MPI-Data-Distribution-Functions.html), the function fftw_mpi_local_size_3d returns the number of **complex** numbers that you should allocate in the current node for that transform, regardless of whether the transform is c2c, c2r or r2c. However, given the arguments passed to this function there's no way for it to figure which of these you'll be doing, and so, in the case of 1 single node, it will always return n_grid*n_grid*n_grid, which is roughly twice as much as it's really necessary (I'm trying to save as much memory as possible). Knowing this, it would be possible to just divide the output of fftw_mpi_local_size_3d by n_grid and then multiply it by (n_grid/2+1) in order to find the actual number of complex elements to be allocated for c2r/r2c, but I'm worried about whether this is safe for an arbitrary number of nodes (I can't think of a reason why not).

A related question would be whether or not one can do exactly the same thing when using transposed distributions.

Thanks a lot in advance for the answers.